# How can i detect objects using Camera to generate a response in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am building an android app to help people blind walk, so I am wondering if there is any way i can use a camera to determine if the path is clear or there are any objects on the way, and based on that generate a response.. say haptic feedback..

Comment: The general topic is called computer vision or image recognition and is a very broad topic. Libraries such as OpenCV or even specialized hardware like Google's Tango tablet may be appropriate. You may want to do more research and come back with a more specific problem.

Comment: There is a list of sdks that will help you recognize objects with a camera, but you have to understand that it looks for familiar features in an image so you won't be able to create a magical app that can tell all obstacles from a path. But you could teach it to recognize a few easy to see objects.

http://augmentedrealitynews.org/ar-sdk/top-5-augmented-reality-sdks/